# Solving equilibrium with python

Tags: python

I try to solve the codility demo problem with my own program.
while I run it by my own I successfully detect the equilibrium. But it always show my answer is not right when the codility evaluates my answer.
here is my code:

```
i = 0
for N in range(0, len(A)-1):
    lnum = 0
    rnum = 0
    if N == 0:
        lnum = 0
    elif N ==1:
        lnum = A[0]
    else:
        for num1 in A[:N-1]:
            lnum += num1

    for num2 in A[N+1:]:
        rnum += num2

    if lnum == rnum:
        return N
return -1
```

Can anyone explain to me why is this happening? 
ps: I use two `if` statements because when `N` equals 0, the sum of left side equals 0, and when `N` equals 1, `A[0:0]` will not give me the number index 0 point at.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: @shadow, sorry first time post. It has been fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution(A):
    l=len(A)
    for i in range(0,l):
        lnum=0                   #reset the sum of left to zero for every index
        rnum=0                   #      ""         right         ""
        for numl in range(0,i):         #sum up all values on left indices
            lnum+=A[numl]
        for numr in range(i+1,l):       #sum up all values on the right indices
            rnum+=A[numr]
        if lnum==rnum:                  #if the sum of left is equal to right...
            return i                    #return the index of equilibrium
        else:
            pass
    return -1 #no equilibrium!
```

This should work 95%
Codility has its own test cases which are run on your code, so testing the code in your own environment will not guarantee pass on the codility.